# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

Tags: php, pdo

Been stuck here for some time.

I am receiving this error when I try to run the code:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ProjectWebSite/php/PDO.php on
>   line 111

Line 111 is the first line of the code

```
$result1 = $query1->execute( array( ':transactionID'=>$transactionID, ':personalID'=>$array['personalID'], 
            ':description'=>$array['description'], ':cost'=>$array['cost'], ':datetime'=>$array['datetime'] )  );




function createTransaction($array){
    $db = connection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("Select MAX(`transactionID`)+1 AS transactionID FROM transaction ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $transactionID = null;
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $transactionID =$result['transactionID'];
    }

    if(isset($transactionID)){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `transaction`(`transactionID`, `personalID`, `description`, `cost`, `dateTime`)"
            . " VALUES (:transactinID,:personalID,:description,:cost,CAST(:datetime AS DATETIME)";
        $query1 = $db->prepare( $sql );

        $result1 = $query1->execute( array( ':transactionID'=>$transactionID, ':personalID'=>$array['personalID'], 
            ':description'=>$array['description'], ':cost'=>$array['cost'], ':datetime'=>$array['datetime'] )  );
        var_dump($result1);
        if ( $result1 ){
     return $transactionID;
        }
             return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in your query:

`:transactinID` should be `:transactionID`

Answer (score 0):

It simple you got a typo:
replace:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `transaction`(`transactionID`, `personalID`, `description`, `cost`, `dateTime`)"
            . " VALUES (:transactinID,:personalID,:description,:cost,CAST(:datetime AS DATETIME)";
```

with:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `transaction`(`transactionID`, `personalID`, `description`, `cost`, `dateTime`)"
            . " VALUES (:transactionID,:personalID,:description,:cost,CAST(:datetime AS DATETIME)";
```